# A suggestion for a statistical test or Model to Prove the regression results

Tags: r, regression, hypothesis-testing, paired-data

I am working with the following dataset.  (I attached a screenshot of some of my data):

[image]

Data name is HTO and has the following variables $x$ and $y$, pre- and post-test, and the delta ($\Delta$) values for both $x$, $y$ (difference between $x$ and $y$). A multiple regression analysis showed that $\Delta y$ can be significantly predicted by $x_\text{post}$ and $y_\text{pre}$.

I want to find out what degree of $x_\text{post}$ can predict what degree of $\Delta y$? How can I do this and prove this statistically?

Comment: What model did you run to discover that "Delta Y can be significantly predicted by `X_POST` and `Y_PRE`" ? And please explain what you mean by "I want to find out what degree of X_POST can predict what degree of DELTA_Y?"

Comment: I used simple linear regression model. All the variables are angles for bone deformity correction. I want to find out e.g. after what degree of X_POST,  DELTA_Y increases

Comment: If you ran a simple multivariable regression then the regression coefficient for X_POST tells you what you want to know.

Comment: How to do that? I am not that expert?

Comment: Ok then please edit the question and add the output from the regression model.

Comment: I'm still confused by what you are looking for. You said *all* the variables are angles for bone deformity correction. So then what is the $x$ here and what is the $y$? That really isn't clear from the question and should be clarified.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, please understand that we can never "prove" anything with statistics. Instead we can conduct a statistical test that, in a frequentist setting (not a Bayesian setting), provides evidence against a null hypothesis.

I am assuming that you have conducted your regression in a frequentist setting.

So when you run your regression model, you will obtain a regression coefficient for the variable of interest, in your case `X_POST`. This estimate tells you that when `X_POST` changes by 1 unit, the outcome variable changes by whatever the value of whatever the regression coefficient for `X_POST` is. Along with that, there should also be a standard error, a t-value and a p-value. The p-value tells you, that if the "real" value of the coefficient was actually zero (ie no effect) then the probability of you obtaining the data that you did (or even more extreme) is given by the p-value, which is a probability. The smaller this probability is, the less likely that it arose by chance, if the null hypothesis were true. Here the null hypothesis would be "that the value of the regression coefficient is zero", ie, this variable has zero linear association with the outcome.

If you would rather just like to estimate the probablity that null hypothesis is true (zero effect) then you could adopt a Bayesian approach.